# How to make a model's entries as a field.options list in other model's field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models - `Account`, like checking, wallet, credit, etc. and `Transaction` which includes each purchase and earning. `Transaction` has a foreign key to `Account`.

In `Transaction`, I want users to select the `Account` of purchase. I considered the [field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#:%7E:text=choices%C2%B6-,Field.choices%C2%B6,-A%20sequence%20consisting) but the choices are permanent.

I want users to select a choice of `Account` from `Account` models. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a django form for creating/updating transaction model objects, then it will default to a selection field with all of your Account model objects as options. Model foreign key fields default in django forms as a `ModelChoiceField` which will render to a template as `<select>`.